# two datasource in Spring integration inbound channel

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using `int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter` of Spring Integration.

My Query is how to use two different datasource i.e. datasource A for querying and datasource B for update , in a single adapter?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot; the same `JdbcTemplate` is used for both operations; you can omit the  update query and do the update on an outbound channel adapter.

Comment: Hi Gary _ I see you point, could you please help me in understanding the below....<br>1. I have to select for IDs(more than 1) from datasource A . <br> 2. Then I have to pass these Ids to select query 2 using datsource B. <br> 3. Finally the output of point 2, i have to utilize for update using datsource A

Comment: Don't try to put logic in comments, it doesn't render well. Edit the question instead. You need `jcbc-inbound-adapter->jdbc-outbound-gateway->jdbc-oubound-adapter` with whatever necessary transformers in between.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring JDBC module we have something like `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. 
Which you can implement based on some `ThreadLocal` variable.

From other side the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` has code like this:

```
private Object poll() {
    List<?> payload = doPoll(this.sqlQueryParameterSource);
    ...
    executeUpdateQuery(payload);

    return payload;
}
```

So, you should somehow to hook in between `doPoll()` and `executeUpdateQuery` and, therefore, change the key in the `ThreadLocal` to be able to switch to another `DataSource` in the `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.

I only the hack like custom `sqlParameterSourceFactory.createParameterSource()` and the `ThreadLocal` modification there. Just because the code is like:

```
private void executeUpdateQuery(Object obj) {
    SqlParameterSource updateParamaterSource = this.sqlParameterSourceFactory.createParameterSource(obj);
    this.jdbcOperations.update(this.updateSql, updateParamaterSource);
}
```

(Will commit the fix for `updateParamaterSource` typo soon :-)).

But! As Gary mentioned in his answer, it would be better to have several JDBC adapters for different `DataSource`s : one for `SELECT` and another for `UPDATE`. Both of them may work in the same XA Transaction (`<transactional>` on the `<poller>`). And from there we really differentiate the business logic and level of responsibility.